# How to cleanup unnecessary intermediate build results (like .o files) after compiling GCC from source?

Tags: gcc

I have built GCC 13.1 from source code. The source folder after building (with all the parameters at their defaults) is 6.9 GiB in size. In total my free space reduces by 11 GiB after compiling (not including the size of the sources themselves).

I suspect some of this is just dead weight, but I can't find any standard procedure for cleaning up after full source build. Did anyone research this topic?

Comment: `Did anyone research this topic?` did you?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I did, but to no avail.

Comment: `make clean` for a start

Comment: @JaromandaX: won't that remove the actual built binaries?

Comment: haven't you done a `make install` or some such as per build instructions?

Comment: I have, but it doesn't seem to move the new libstdc++ anywhere, for example. I had to add the build location to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and I'm pretty sure `clean` will remove these libraries. Will check what's with the GCC binaries themselves, but I expect they also reside in the build root and are symlinked to become globally available.

Comment: You're right, so you aren't installing GCC into your system correctly in that case - what instructions did you follow?

Comment: I have followed the only instruction I could find - https://gcc.gnu.org/install/finalinstall.html I looked for a better installation procedure but didn't find anything else.

Comment: and you've done every `make` on that page, but you think gcc is not installed correctly? When you run those makes, where is it "installing"? Read the 3rd paragraph on that page